# A simple two variable functional equation: $f(x+y,y) = f(x,0)+qy$

Tags: functional-equations

A real function $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfies $f(x+y,y) = f(x,0)+qy$ for some real number $q$. What form should $f$ assume (without assuming $f$ is continuous)? Is the linear solution $f(x,y)=ax+(q-a)y$ for some constant real number $a$ the unique continuous or differentiable solution?

Comment: Let $g$ be an arbitrary function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x,y)=g(x-y)+qy$ is, if I am not wrong, a solution.

Comment: @Kelenner: You are right. Could you explain a bit how you came up with this particular solution? What is the most general solution then?

Comment: If $f$ is a solution, put $g(x)=f(x,0)$; Then replace in the equation $x$ by $x-y$. You get $f(x,y)=g(x-y)+qy$. So this is the general solution.

Comment: @Kelenner: I actually got $f(x,y)=f(x-y,0)+qy$ but did not go further and realize $f(x,0)$ could just be taken to be an arbitrary function. Thank you.

Comment: @Kelenner please write down your correct answer, and close this question with approve the answer by Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If $f$ is a solution, put $g(x)=f(x,0)$; Then replace in the equation $x$ by $x−y$. You get $f(x,y)=g(x−y)+qy$.

b) Now let $g$ be an arbitrary function on $\mathbb{R}$. Put $f(x,y)=g(x-y)+qy$. It is easy to see that $f$ is a solution.

c) Hence the general solution of the functional equation is $f(x,y)=g(x-y)+qy$, with $g$ an arbitrary function.